# XPATH query to filter values on certain attributes only

Tags: xpath

I have following XML:

```
<Library>
 <Item>
  <Field Name="Name">smooth</Field>
  <Field Name="File Type">mid</Field>
  <Field Name="File Size">60026</Field>
 </Item>
 <Item>
  <Field Name="Name">mid</Field>
  <Field Name="File Type">mp3</Field>
  <Field Name="File Size">4584972</Field>
 </Item>
</Library>
```

I'd like to get all item names of items of the file type "mid". My XPATH query looks as

```
/Library/Item/Field
    [
    @Name="Name" and 
    (../Field[@Name="File Type" and ../Field[.="mid"]])
    ]
```

But unfortunately both items are returned from that query.

```
smooth
mid
```

Seems that the last condition is not checked against fields with the attribute "File Type" only, but all fields. Which results in a return of the name "mid", even if this item is of file type "mp3".

How can I restrict the comparison with "mid" to the value of the field with the attribute Name="File Type"?

Can anybody suggest me an XPATH syntax which works as expected?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

XPath predicates can be applied anywhere, this would be more straight-forward:

```
/Library/Item[Field[@Name="File Type"] = "mid"]/Field[@Name="Name"]
```

Your own expression would be correct as

```
/Library/Item/Field[
  @Name="Name" 
  and ../Field[@Name="File Type"] = "mid"
]
```