# Trouble with XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have never used XML much and need some help reading a complex file. [image]

I am trying to get to the number that is nested in:
outputTree\command\heading\pivotTable\dimension\category\dimension\category\dimension\group\category\call:Text(number)

I just have no idea how to do it.
if anyone could show me some basics of this it would be helpful all the examples I see are very basic and don't have this many levels so I am having issues understanding how to get to this level.

thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the nature of your trouble? Have you looked at the docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx?

Comment: I have and I am confused by it, I am trying to get to the element in the XML document but every time I run it, I can never seem to find that element data. I believe my request was clear I am trying to get to that element but I can no idea how to do it.

Comment: I am using this code to read the document:using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("c:/temp/descriptives_table.xml"))
                {
                    reader.ReadStartElement("outputTree");

                    while (reader.Name == "category")
                    {
                        XElement el = (XElement)XNode.ReadFrom(reader);
                    }

                    reader.ReadEndElement();
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [XPath query](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/). Based on the structure of your document, this should snag you the precise value you are looking for:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\path\to\file.xml");
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

nsManager.AddNamespace(
    "oms",
    "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms");

var cell = xml.XPathSelectElement(
    "oms:outputTree/oms:command[@text='Regression']/" +
    "oms:heading[@text='uid = 1015984.00']/" +
    "oms:pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']/" +
    "oms:dimension/oms:category/oms:dimension/oms:category/" +
    "oms:dimension/oms:group/oms:category/oms:cell",
    nsManager);

var number = (decimal)cell.Attribute("number");

Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Tweak as necessary.  You will need these imports:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

Comment: I don't see any LINQ to XML here.

Comment: Cell is returning null

Comment: @James XDocument is defined in the System.Xml.Linq namespace, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Comment: @user1221399 I didn't see your `xmlns` attribute in the root element.  It's probably a namespace issue.  Let me take a look and revise my answer.

Comment: @user1221399 Updated with namespace qualifiers.  For some reason, it didn't work if I mapped the OMS namespace as the default.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten OK I rephrase, there is no LINQ here.

Answer (score 1):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282579/xpath-query-to-filter-values-on-certain-attributes-only), you can select the XML Node directly using an advanced XPath filter

such as:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("<fileName>");
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("outputTree/command/heading[@text='uid = 1015984.00']/pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']/dimension[@text='Model']");
```

etc.

see this for a list of examples:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So when I do this:
XmlNode node = results.SelectSingleNode("/outputTree/command/heading/pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']");
It returns null

Comment: try leaving off the first "/" before outputTree and make sure all of the paths match up

Comment: Tried: 
XmlNode node = results.SelectSingleNode("outputTree/command/heading/pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']");
Still null

Comment: Try filtering on the "heading" tag as well. there may be other 'heading' elements. See my edit.

Comment: Any time you're attempting to select an XPath where there may be multiple choices made, you should ensure that the exact path that you want is selected by filtering on some attribute.

Comment: I see I have to extend the nodes let me check it.

Comment: I tried this still getting null:
XmlNode node = results.SelectSingleNode("outputTree/command/heading/pivotTable[@text='Coefficients']/dimension[@text='Model']/category[@text='1']/dimension[@text='Variables']/category[@text='(Constant)']/dimension[@text='Statitics']/group[@text='Unstandardised Coefficients']/category[@text='(B)']");

Comment: I recommend starting small. Start at the XPath and see what that returns. Then add the second argument. For something as complex as this file, it may be best to take an incremental approach.

Comment: For example, make sure that document.SelectSingleNode("outputTree") returns the outputTree. Then move on to ensuring that document.SelectSingleNode("outputTree/command/") returns the correct command, etc

Comment: you know what is crazy I do this:
XmlNode node = results.SelectSingleNode("outputTree");
and it returns null
So I try this:
XmlNode node = results.SelectSingleNode("/outputTree");
null
XmlNode node = results.SelectSingleNode("//outputTree");
null

Crazy

Answer (score 0):

I think I am going to end up doing this and add some if statements in to catch the data I am looking for:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("c:/temp/descriptives_table.xml");
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);

                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                            Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Thank you all for your help! and leading me to this path!