# How to use XPath to filter elements by the value of another property?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have this

```
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/job/entries/entry/name/text()");
```

I need to filter by the text value of the **type** property so I only get the entry objects that have the value JOB in the **type**.

```
<job>
 <entries>
    <entry>
      <name>OperationalDataStoreToReconciled</name>
      <description/>
      <type>JOB</type>
    </entry>
 </entries>
</job>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath select based on child value(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027096/xpath-select-based-on-child-values)

Comment: Is it not your case?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282579/xpath-query-to-filter-values-on-certain-attributes-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below xpath.

```
 //job/entries/entry[./type[.='JOB']]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]